# Crystal Reports requires logon on every time a report is loaded using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, crystal-reports-2008

Whenever I load a Crystal Report it asks for my login information. 
I have added my code below. Can any body help me to solve this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TxtCustomer.Text == "" && TxtSONofrom.Text == "" && TxtSONoto.Text == "" && DTSODateFrom.Text != "" && DTSODateTO.Text != "")
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do You Want to Print This Report?", "YESNO", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            BrownERP.ReportViewer cr = new BrownERP.ReportViewer();
            cr.BringToFront();
            cr.Show();
            BrownERP.QuatationReport QTNREP = new BrownERP.QuatationReport();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionpath);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Tbl_QTN where SODate between CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + DTSODateFrom.Text + "',103) and CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + DTSODateTO.Text + "',103) ", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds, "Tbl_QTN");
            QTNREP.SetDataSource(ds);

            cr.CRV.ReportSource = QTNREP;
            cr.CRV.Refresh();
            con.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating a new connection to SQL every time you click button1.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionpath);
con.Open();
```

It will prompt you for credentials if you have not included credentials in your "connectionpath".

I am guessing your "connectionpath" currently looks something like this.

```
"Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME"
```

So you can modify it to use integrated security, ie the windows user running the application.

```
"Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

Or modify to use a specific username and password

```
"Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;User ID=YourUserID;Password=YourPassword"
```

Doing this should stop it prompting you each time, but it will create, open and then close the connection each time button1 is clicked. If you wanted to Open the connection and do multiple reports while the connection is open you will need to construct this outside of button1. I would recommend putting a timeout on it though.

Help on SQL Connection Class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2